# Как правильно завершить работу с потоком?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, потоки-данных

Есть WCF служба, которая открывает поток из файла и возвращает клиенту в сообщении.

Клиент считывает этот поток и закачивает файл.

Так вот, когда клиент скачал файл, файл на сервере остается занятым.

Как решить эту проблему? Пробовал обромлять  `Stream`

на стороне службы в `using`, но в таком случае вылетает сразу же ошибка...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любой поток должен быть закрыт после открытия и полагаться в этом на клиентскую сторону не стоит. Поток должен быть закрыть на севере. Чтобы это сделать есть два варианта

- уставноить `OperationBehaviorAttribute.AutoDisposeParameters` равным `true`
- Использовать `OperationCompleted event`, описание в [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.operationcompleted.aspx?tduid=%285376a5cb336beda272e7b093c82cc85a%29%28256380%29%282459594%29%28TnL5HPStwNw-FmA5ILwdcokPyZCLuQGQig%29%28%29)

Вариант закрытия потока при срабатывании ивента:

```
public Stream GetFile(string path) 
{
    Stream fileStream = null;    

    try   
    {
        fileStream = File.OpenRead(path);
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }

    OperationContext clientContext = OperationContext.Current;
    clientContext.OperationCompleted += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (fileStream != null)
            fileStream.Dispose();
    });

    return fileStream;
}
```

[Источник](https://devdump.wordpress.com/2008/12/07/disposing-return-values/)

Comment: а если на стороне клиента произойдет ошибка, то OperationCompleted отработает ?

Comment: @iluxa1810, вам остается только создать эту искусственную ситуацию, проверить и рассказать нам :) В теории, поток который созадется на сервере и поток который получает клиент это совершенно разные потоки. Клиент не может управлять потоком который был создан на сервере, поэтому сервер создаст поток, отправит его и вызовет ивент OperationCompleted. Клиент получит же так сказать копию и что там произойдет с ним на стороне клиента, серверу абсолютно не важно.

Comment: @iluxa1810, такой подход идеальный, если вы просто отправляете пользователю файл и вам нужно просто освободить ресурсы. Однако, в случае операций удаления или перемещения это не самый лучший вариант, так как вам нужно быть увереным что файл был считан на другой стороне и только тогда закрывать поток и удалять файл с сервера. Но это уже совсем другая история :)

Comment: Такой вопрос, допустим я обрамил прокси клиент с using, разве когда я выхожу за его пределы не должен уничтожаться экземпляр службы и освобождать файл?